# How to create thumbnail from videos using Python

Tags: python, thumbnails

My video formats are jpeg,yuy2 etc.Need to convert into thumbnails. Is there a default size for thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to work with videos (converting, thumbnail creation, ...). There is a good package to work with ffpmeg in python named [python-video-converter](https://github.com/senko/python-video-converter). You can have control over each parameter using ffmpeg. Also using great Pillow package on python, you can manipulate images easily.

Comment: Now am able to get the thumbnail and now i want to set that image on the existing video.